# Vertical scroll within group

Tags: reactjs, konvajs, react-konva

I'm working on a canvas with draggable nodes. Some of the nodes contain a list of items which I display on the canvas. I'm currently rendering all the item under each other. The structure I'm currently rendering looks looks like the following:

```
<Group>
    <Rect height={40} width={100}>
    <Rect height={40} width={100}>
    <Rect height={40} width={100}>
    <Rect height={40} width={100}>
<Group>
```

The problem I'm currently facing is that my canvas is very unclear when the list of Rect's gets very long. I would like to add a vertical scroll whenever the total heigh of all the Rect's combined is larger than a certain amount. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: This tutorial should help you: https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Canvas_Scrolling.html